# How to set node label by bare meta Ubuntu getting started guide?

Tags: kubernetes

I have install k8s by bare meta Ubuntu getting started guide.  How to set node label?  I think to set several categories for nodes. And I create rc on same caterory nodes. How write rc file(yml or json)?

Comment: The documentation provides the answer to this: http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/node-selection/README.html. If that does not help, please update your question to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

to add a label to the node you've chosen, run `kubectl label nodes <node-name> <label-key>=<label-value>`

from the doc quoted above.